# H3-go library not running

Tags: go, h3

I am newbie to golang who usually uses python.
what I did:

1. copied sample from https://github.com/uber/h3-go
2. pasted it in local machine
3. Run `go run main.go` which was the code placed.
   The output:
   **github.com/uber/h3-go/v4: build constraints exclude all Go files in C:\Users\User\go\pkg\mod\github.com\uber\h3-go\v4@v4.1.0**

couldn't solve myself with google, chatgpt.

go version: *go version go1.20.3 windows/amd64*

Comment: I run it on wsl after windows itself couldn't run. on golang it worked well. some people recommended to build it at first and run it after build